# how does python Django some_item|divisiblyby:"2" work

Tags: python, django

Just saw this in a Django tutorial. I'm confused on the syntax here and how this works. Isn't | the bitwise OR? Can someone please explain to me how this works?

the code in the Django tutorial is exactly as follows:

```
{% if some_item|divisibleby:"2" %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are template filters. You can think of them a little like pipes in unix-like systems. They take a value and alter it with a function. More here: http://django.readthedocs.io/en/1.3.X/topics/templates.html#filters

Comment: Ah ok thanks I was having a hard time looking that syntax up. So is it Django specific to use | in that way? Or doe that syntax exist in Python as well (outside the use of bitwise OR)?

Comment: This is the Django template syntax, not python.

Comment: Lots more built in filters here: http://django.readthedocs.io/en/1.3.X/ref/templates/builtins.html#ref-templates-builtins-filters. Especially handy for formatting date objects.

Answer (score 1):

No, in django templating engine it is known as filters.

Firat the value what is there on the left side is put and then is checked by the right handed filter. The one here simply means that the value%2==0 or not

You can pass mutiple filters using |

Like 
{% if some_item|add:"2"|divisibleby:"2" %}
Which would evaluate to first add 2 to the value then check whether its divisible by 2

Comment: so using | in such a way is syntax specific for Django correct? That's not anywhere else in the Pyhton language outside of bitwise OR right?

Comment: Yes. But only in djnago template and not in python code